# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_custom_scripts' not found or invalid function name

Tags: errors

I have facing a problem of this error from last week. I search a lot on google but didn't find any solution. https://delegatehosting.com/ This is my website and

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'add_custom_scripts' not found or invalid function
>   name in /home/www/delegatehosting.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 286.

This is the issue which i facing

Answer (score 0):

[`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) takes a valid callable function as second parameter. Wordpress is unable to find `add_custom_scripts` function which is being used to add some custom scripts probably, may be its not defined anywhere. You might have to look into `fucntions.php` file of your active theme/child-theme, find the `add_action` where second parameter is passed `add_custom_scripts`. There are two things you can do after finding this line.

1. Change the `add_custom_scripts` to a valid callable function.
2. Comment that line if you don't need want to use that .